# How to manage User docs permission setting using Google Drive Api? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am new to Google Drive SDK.
 I followed

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert?hl=en

this examples where they show how to change permissions for file. I'm able run this code but my problem is that i want to change permission of more than one file.i tried some loop for user and inside it fileId loop but because javascript not wait for child function complete(asynchronous calling function), it wont work for me

Please Help me

Following is my Code...
i get very confused in it please help me to sort out this

This the Code Please Correct me here Please

```
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

      // Use a button to handle authentication the first time.
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        //window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
        checkAuth();
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
      function makeApiCall() {
        var fileID = new Array();
        var email = new Array();
        fileID[0] = "1fEYDfB9owJAdxQ7lI0";
        fileID[1] = "1YYcKn1ZsiPYWA";

        email[0] = "email1@email.com";
        email[1] = "email2@email.com";
        email[2] = "email3@email.com";

          gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
              for(var i=0;i<email.length;i++)
              {
                  var body = {
                            'value': email[i],
                            'type': "user",
                            'role': "reader"
                          };
                  for(var j=0;j<fileID.length;j++)
                    {

                        var fileid = fileID[j];

                       excuteRequest(body, fileid, function() { 
                              var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
                                    'fileId': fileid,
                                    'resource': body
                                  });
                            request.execute(function(resp) { });
                        }); 
                    }
              }
          });
    }

      function excuteRequest(param1, param2, callback) {

            if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
                callback();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question would better fit under [javascript].

Answer (score 3):

Use a flow control library, similar to `async`: https://github.com/caolan/async

```
var files = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
async.each(files, function(fileId, callback){

  gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
     'fileId': fileId,
     'resource': body
  }).execute(function(response) {
      callback(null, response);
  });

}, function(err){
  if (!err) { console.log('done.'); }
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply... i will try this but please can u tell me if i have two array one is USERS array and Another one is FILE-ID Array for each user i want to share each file...

Comment: SyntaxError: missing formal parameter at async.each(files, function(fileId, callback) this line

Comment: hi can u explain me what shuld be the callback

Comment: not working for me.....
i tried with 3 user and 2 file id, this code only able to share 1 user

Comment: m trying this in simple
for(userEmailID loop...)
{
for(FILEID looop...)
{
    var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
  'fileId': fileid,
                'resource': body
  });
request.execute(function(resp){});

}
}

Comment: i tried this also but not work for me :( function is getting call but not wait till complete. form get submitedd. i am to share file between all users. i think i need a function to wait till share function get run completely...

Comment: can i use $.Deferred() here for this?? if u know about it then please can u explain me ?

Comment: hi sir m adding some code can explain me using this code please

Comment: i hope u will get my problem please help me